# When Condition with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible, and I am writing a script to install a package when disk space is more then a limit. I am getting error like this >>  error while evaluating conditional

```
---
- hosts: dev
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: Install zsh if enough space
      yum:
       name: zsh
       state: latest
       with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts}}"
      when: item.mount == "/" and item.size_available > 10737400
```

I am giving the size in bytes. ( Is there a way to give the size in MB ? )

Thanks.

Comment: `item.size_available / 1024 / 1024 > 10`?

Comment: always check the syntax of the playbook before executing it using..ansible-playbook --syntax-check

Answer (score 1):

Ansible uses the YAML format, you need to use the right indent.
In YAML, the indent is important as closing brackets or semicolons in most programming languages.

`with_items` is not a definition for the `yum` module, it is a directive for Ansible, so it should be at the same level as `when` and the module call (e.g. `yum`). Both examples below should work:

```
---
- hosts: dev
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: Install zsh if enough space
     yum:
       name: zsh
       state: latest
     with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
     when: item.mount == "/" and item.size_available > 10737400
```

or

```
---
- hosts: dev
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
   - name: Install zsh if enough space
     with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
     when: item.mount == "/" and item.size_available > 10737400
     yum:
       name: zsh
       state: latest
```